# Elastic Search number of object passed must be even

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning about elastic search and I am following [the next tutorial](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/primeros-pasos-elasticsearch/), but I get the next error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The number of object passed must be even but was [1]
at  org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest.source(IndexRequest.java:451)
at elastic.elasti.App.lambda$0(App.java:55)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
at elastic.elasti.App.indexExampleData(App.java:53)
at elastic.elasti.App.main(App.java:45)
```

Could you help me to fix it please?

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws TwitterException, UnknownHostException
    {
    System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    List tweetJsonList = searchForTweets();

    Client client = TransportClient.builder().build()
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    String index = "tweets_juan";
    client.admin().indices()
                    .create(new CreateIndexRequest(index))
                    .actionGet();
    indexExampleData(client, tweetJsonList, index);
    searchExample(client);
}
public static void indexExampleData(Client client, List tweetJsonList, String index) {


    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = client.prepareBulk();

    tweetJsonList.forEach((jsonTweet) -> {
        bulkRequestBuilder.add(new IndexRequest(index, "tweets_juan")
                .source(jsonTweet));
    });

    BulkResponse bulkItemResponses = bulkRequestBuilder.get();
}




public static void searchExample(Client client) {
    BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders
            .boolQuery()
            .must(termsQuery("text", "españa"));

    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("tweets_juan")
            .setQuery(queryBuilder)
            .setSize(25)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
     }

public static List searchForTweets() throws TwitterException {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    Query query = new Query("mundial baloncesto");
    List tweetList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        QueryResult queryResult = twitter.search(query);
        tweetList.addAll(queryResult.getTweets());
        if (!queryResult.hasNext()) {
            break;
        }
        query = queryResult.nextQuery();
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    return (List) tweetList.stream().map(gson::toJson).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38):

I know it's late but the simple answer to this is adding `XContentType.JSON` along with source which is available in **ElasticSearch** library package `org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent`

```
public static void indexExampleData(Client client, List tweetJsonList, String index) {


    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = client.prepareBulk();

    tweetJsonList.forEach((jsonTweet) -> {
        bulkRequestBuilder.add(new IndexRequest(index, "tweets_juan")
                .source(jsonTweet,XContentType.JSON));
    });

    BulkResponse bulkItemResponses = bulkRequestBuilder.get();
}
```

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Comment: Also noticed that `XContentType.JSON` should be the second parameter. Putting it as the first parameter does compile, but later yield the same error message.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in OpenSearch. Should reverse the parameters here:
IndexRequest.class
...
    public IndexRequest source(Object... source) {
        return this.source(Requests.INDEX_CONTENT_TYPE, source);
    }

Answer (score 8):

Summary:

1. Json object cannot be used as a source for indexing
2. Either Stringify your json by using something like Jackson or set the source as Map

Jackson:

String stringifiedJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonObject)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library to manage JSON content and encounter this error, you can solve it this way (setting the source as Map as skgemini proposed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39190078/3305789)):

```java
JSONObject dataAsJson = new JSONObject(dataAsJsonFormattedString);
HashMap<String, Object> dataAsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(dataAsJson.toMap());
bulkRequestBuilder.add(new IndexRequest(index, "tweets_juan").source(dataAsMap, XContentType.JSON));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that elastic-search does not allow indexing the JSON object directly using the `RequestIndexer` API. So we need to pass the `XContentType.JSON` as 2nd parameter in `source(sourceStr, XContentType.JSON)` method.

Tested this with the following combinations:

- Elasticsearch version: 7.3.2
- FlinkElasticConnector: flink-connector-elasticsearch7
- Scala version: 2.13.1
- Java version: 11.0.4

**Sample code:**

```scala
def sinkToES(counted: DataStream[(Employee, String)], index: String, indexType: String) = {
    try {
      val esSinkBuilder = new ElasticsearchSink.Builder[(Employee, String)](
        httpHosts, new ElasticsearchSinkFunction[(Employee, String)] {
          def process(element: (Employee, String), ctx: RuntimeContext, indexer: RequestIndexer) {
            val tenant = element._1.asInstanceOf[Employee].tenantId
            val sourceStr = JsonUtils.toJson[Employee](element._1.asInstanceOf[Employee])
            indexer.add(Requests.indexRequest.index(tenant + "_" + index).`type`(indexType).id(element._2).source(sourceStr, XContentType.JSON))
          }
        }
      )
      counted.addSink(esSinkBuilder.build())
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => logger.info("@@@@@@@Exception from this sinkDataToES method:-->" + e.printStackTrace)
    }
  }
```